# static std::function<T> incomplete type

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement static std::function object and I get **incomplete type** error. Why am I getting such an error, the syntax looks fine to me?

With this code the error can be reproduced.

```
    #include <string>
    #include <functional>
    int foobar(std::string){

    }
    class A{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        static std::function<T> foo //error is here;

        template<typename T>
        static void bar(T t){
            A::foo<T> = t;
        }
    };
    int main(){
        A::bar(foobar);
    }
```

while the error is:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ g++ asd.cpp -std=c++17
asd.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void A::bar(T) [with T = int (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)]’:
asd.cpp:17:15:   required from here
asd.cpp:9:26: error: ‘A::foo<int (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>’ has incomplete type
  static std::function<T> foo;
                          ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58:0,
                 from asd.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:147:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::function<int (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>’
     class function;
```

OS: Ubuntu 17.10

GCC: 7.2

Comment: `T` is `int(*)(string)` not `int(string)` as it should be. You need to remove the pointer.

Comment: I fixed it by changing bar's argument to pointer (T* t).
Thank you!